# Format dataframe to equal length time-series format

Tags: python, pandas, outer-join

I have a dataframe

```
time.   item.   value1.   value2
-----------------------------------
1       1       3           4
2       1       2           5
1       2       3           5
3       2       2           1
2       3       3           6
3       3       2           5
```

and I would like to transform it to the following

```
time.   item.   value1.   value2
-----------------------------------
1       1       3           4
2       1       2           5
3       1       nan         nan
1       2       3           5
2       2       nan         nan
3       2       2           1
1       3       nan         nan
2       3       3           6
3       3       2           5
```

where the time range is the same for all items and value1 and value2 are nans if not in the original dataframe. I have done some trials with outer join but without success.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: The output  you provide does not match the requirements, for example `(item=2, time=2)` is not present in the original datframe so this should be `NaN` in the output.

Comment: Thanks, I have just edit the question

Comment: @Ch3ster undelete your solution, i think its correct.

Comment: @Ch3ster had a solution.  `(df.set_index(['time.', 'item.']).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['time.'].unique(), df['item.'].unique()], names=['time.', 'item.'])).reset_index()))`

Comment: I don't see @Ch3ster answer, but it seems correct

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I didn't get a notification that you tagged me, I didnot see that question is edited. Undeleting it.

Comment: @ScottBoston I didn't get a notification that you tagged me. Thanks for taking out time and posting it in the comments. Undeleted it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `time`, `item` as index and then use [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)

```
time = df['time'].unique()
item = df['item'].unique()
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([item, time],names=['item', 'time']).swaplevel(0,1)
df.set_index(['time', 'item']).reindex(idx).reset_index()

   time  item  value1  value2
0     1     1     3.0     4.0
1     2     1     2.0     5.0
2     3     1     NaN     NaN
3     1     2     3.0     5.0
4     2     2     NaN     NaN
5     3     2     2.0     1.0
6     1     3     NaN     NaN
7     2     3     3.0     6.0
8     3     3     2.0     5.0
```